# FEZ touch driver always returns the same X and Y coordinates

Tags: c#, .net, pandaboard

i use the FEZ_Components.FEZTouch control, and when touching the screen, i always get sent the same coordinates:

239,319

Any idea what i am doing wrong?

EDIT

after some debugging, i found that the code in the `while (!terminateTouchThread)` loop always returns x=0 and y=0.
Then, in the `'Calibrate'` section, it always makes the 239,319 of those 0,0 values